# Same API Get diffrent response time

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx

I run the same API  4 times in the same JMeter script. in the 1st running API get the high time and after that same API get low times.

1. User Create API -               2067 ms
2. User Create API 1-               948 ms
3. User Create API 2-               869 ms
4. User Create API 3-               902 ms
5. User Create API 4-               993 ms

why this kind of scenario does in the JMeter??

Answer (score 1):

JMeter only sends requests, waits for responses, measures time in-between and writes down the performance [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) and [KPIs](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis).

If first request takes longer than the following ones the reasons could be in:

1. Your application under test uses [lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) pattern
2. Your application under test needs to [warm up its caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434259/what-is-a-warm-up-cache)
3. First request takes longer due to the process of [establishing the connection](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/three-way-handshake) and subsequent requests are simply re-using the connection if you're sending [Keep-Alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) header
4. Your API endpoint response is [cached](https://www.fortinet.com/resources/cyberglossary/what-is-caching) on database or in-memory level
5. etc. the reasons could be numerous, you need to monitor everything you can on both JMeter and the system under test sides to understand this.

Comment: when I run the same test untick keep-alive 5api call get "2000+ ms" same response time.in this case, I think API gets some time to connect the server. Am I correct??Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter tries to initialize TCP connections and handles SSL handshakes for the first request. For next requests it uses its config parameters `httpclient4.time_to_live` and `httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration`.

You can refer to [Jmeter's properties reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) for more information